# Why is JS's BigInt 98% slower than normal numbers?

Tags: javascript

https://jsperf.com/js-bigint

On my computer, normal numbers are 60x faster than BigInt. In the test cases, the numbers are small enough that BigInt isn't needed. In this case, why don't browsers automatically use normal numbers?

I'm using Chrome 76 on Windows.

Edit: Even a library is faster than the native implementation: https://jsperf.com/js-bigint/4

Comment: The browser isn't supposed to overrule the programmer, is it?

Comment: I think first you need to read about BigInt implementation in v8: https://v8.dev/blog/bigint

Comment: I suspect they could be made a lot faster, but there probably isn't enough incentive because they aren't used very much (and they aren't used very much because they're so slow). V8 shipped a "baseline" implementation in 2018 and I can't find anything to say they ever optimised it.

Answer (score 2):

Some reading about the topic: [The new hotness BigInt](https://v8.dev/features/bigint). The answer is basically due to memory allocation differences and tho the different approach for performing calculations.

More reading: [Representing BigInts in memory](https://v8.dev/blog/bigint#representing-bigints-in-memory)